# Git accidental tag push with forked repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a repository with a synced fork.
Lets call it Software-A and it's synced with the repo of Software-B.

Software B?

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/Software-B/SoftWare-B.git
git fetch upstream
```

I wanted to create a new release for Software-A

```
git tag -s mysoftware-0.4
git push --tags
```

but suddenly I see a couple hundred tags from Software-B.

How can I undo this?

Comment: you mean Software-B is the fork repo for Software-A?

Comment: git remote add upstream https://github.com/softwareB/SoftwareB.git
git fetch upstream

Comment: And yes indeed a fork

Comment: Since you have solved the problem, you can mark your answer and it will help other who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a script for it since I wasn't planning to delete every tag/release by hand.
Everything left on 0.10.x were a few versions which I did delete individual.

Script:

```
for t in `git tag`
do
    version="v0.10.*"
    if [[ $t =~ $version || $t = "origin" ]]; then
        echo $t "is safe and won't be deleted";
else
        echo "deleted: " $t
        git tag -d $t
        git push origin :refs/tags/$t
fi
done
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the tags from SoftwareB manually, any of the below command can works:

```
git push origin --delete tag tagname
git push origin :refs/tags/tagname
```